# I just want a curly brace around the left side of an align environment

Tags: align

I want to slap a vertical curly brace around the left side of an align environment containing two equations. That's it. 5 different stackexchange articles have failed to accurately describe how to do this dispute claiming an answer, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which you are referring to so that we don't go pointing you to them as well.

Comment: We can’t help you know without knowing specifics of what you tried, and what was unsatisfactory about the output — when you say it “didn’t work”, do you mean it just have an error message, or it compiled but the result wasn’t what you wanted?

Comment: Oh, come on, surely there is more you want from life than that. Say, happiness, love, something to eat? Maybe an end to the pandemic? Candy? A remake of GoT season 8?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain in more detail the exact output you want to obtain (maybe with a hand-drawn mockup). There are many, many ways one could add braces in an `align` environment and it is not clear to me what exactly you want. For example https://gist.github.com/moewew/d0ddbedb9ff53878e1c47f72d44fead9 lists some simple things you can do, but I'm not sure if that is what you want or need (I'm guessing it's not because I think those options would have been discussed in the many questions you already read).

Comment: @Plergux at this point I'm going to say all of them. Just pick a random one and I've probably tried it.

Comment: @PhiEarl All right then, without meaning to sound rude, do you expect us to go through all of them as well to see what doesn't work? We can't help you unless we at least know what you have at the moment and what you're trying to achieve. Then we could reference to "curly brace posts" and see why it might not be working.

Comment: I don't expect you to go through any of the necessarily, I expect you to do nothing more than to offer what you learned from your personal experience as a solution. What I have is an align environment. That's it. You can put any symbol you want in it, I don't care. Take that align environment and put a vertical curly brace around the left side of it. Then that is the desired effect.

Comment: One thing you've failed to tell us is whether you want the aligned equations to be numbered.  This makes a great difference, and it's wasted effort if the attempted answer isn't what is wanted.  Even knowing the question numbers of the ones you can't use would provide useful guidance.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No because that's not relevant in any remote capacity. The numbers appear on the far far far far far far right side in an align environment by default.

Comment: @PhiEarl -- What *is* relevant is whether you want a separate equation number on each line.  `cases` has only one equation number, but it can't produce a different number for each line.  Since apparently you are happy with only a single number, I am glad that the matter is settled.  There *is* a way to get a separate number for each line, but I'm rather tired of being told, after trying to provide satisfactory answers for under-specified requests, that what I've provided isn't what was wanted, I prefer to ask for a more specific characterization.

Comment: You didn't try to provide anything. Someone else tried, you didn't, that was the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this satisfy your needs?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{align}
         \begin{cases}
            ab &= cd \\
            cd23 &= 1
        \end{cases}
        \end{align}
            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I don't know why other articles couldn't do this, it may be because they are overall too messy and made the answer convoluted with all kinds of extra conflicting packages.

Comment: Hm, to my opinion bad typography.

Comment: the spacing of cases is designed for the right hand side to have the "cases" when the left hand side applies. It is totally wrong spacing for an equation, not the asymmetric spacing around the = here.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
         \left\{\begin{aligned}
              a & = \sqrt{c^2 - b^2}    \\
            c^2 & = a^2 + b^2
                \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]